# Редактируемая таблица

Tags: android, java

Как сделать редактируемую таблицу в Android? Хотелось бы узнать, как она вообще должна выглядеть и взаимодействовать с пользователем. Предполагается, что пользователь может выбрать один из нескольких определенных пунктов (типа `combo-box`) для ячейки. Я не нашел ни в одном приложении редактируемых таблица. Где, может быть можно, подобное посмотреть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Готового элемента для создания редактируемой таблицы в Android API нет. В упрощенном варианте можно выбрать TableLayout и внутрь ячеек разместить EditText, что-то вроде такого

```
 <TableLayout>
     <TableRow>
         <EditText android:text="one" />
         <EditText android:text="two" />
     </TableRow>
     <TableRow>
         <EditText android:text="three" />
         <EditText android:text="four" />
     </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

Для более сложных случаев (особенно при наличии больших объемов данных) нужно цеплять GridView, а внутрь ячеек помещать также EditText.

Comment: А чем отличается `TableLayout` от `GridView`, кроме наличия скроллера?

Comment: TableLayout - просто таблица, а GridView - отображение данных через адаптер типа ListView.